# Facing issue while showing the error messages in Partial View using unobstructive JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Following is my Area in MVC3

[image]

**Model**

```
public class AdminModule
{
    [Display(Name = "My Name")]
    [Required]
    public String MyName { get; set; }
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model _1.Areas.Admin.Models.AdminModule
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(i => i.MyName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.MyName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.MyName)
    <p id="getDateTimeString">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Click here" id="btn" />
}

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var $form = $("#myForm");

        // Unbind existing validation
        $form.unbind();
        $form.data("validator", null);

        // Check document for changes
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);

        // Re add validation with changes
        $form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);

        if ($(this).valid()) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("Index_partialPost", "Admin", 
                                                new { area = "Admin" })';
            $.post(url, null, function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#myForm').html(data);
            });
        }
        else

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index_partialPost(AdminModule model)
{
    return PartialView("_PartialPage1", model);
} 

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index_partial()
{
    return PartialView("_PartialPage1");
}
```

**Whenever I submit the form and leaves the required field empty. it goes to server i think. I checked here...**

[image]

**My confusion is** => How can I modify my below mentioned code to display the same validation messages mentioned in model at client end using $.post ?

Comment: Have you considered using the unobtrusive client-side scripts included with MVC? They do this automatically for you..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - I have to consider showing validation messages mention in the model via client side.

Comment: They do. They use the validation messages in your data annotations and put them in `data-` attributes on your elements. Then the javascript uses them to display error messages.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - Kindly share a link.

Comment: @SMC You can have a look at this [Unobtrusive Client Validation from msdn](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript) and this [blog post from Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enable unobtrusive client side validation. Start by adding the following script reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
```

and then:

```
@model _1.Areas.Admin.Models.AdminModule
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(i => i.MyName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.MyName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.MyName)
    <p id="getDateTimeString"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Click here" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#myForm').html(data);

                $('#myForm').removeData('validator');
                $('#myForm').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myForm');
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

---

UPDATE:

Now that you sent me your actual code by email I see that there are a hell lot of a problems with it. Instead of going through all of them I prefer to completely rewrite everything from scratch.

So we start by the `~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage1.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
        </ul>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Notice how I moved all scripts to the bottom of the file as well as added a specifically dedicated section where custom scripts will be placed.

Next we move to the `~/Areas/Admin/Views/Admin/Index.cshtml`:

```
@model _1.Areas.Admin.Models.AdminModule
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";
}

<div id="formContainer" data-url="@Url.Action("Index_partial", "Admin", new { area = "Admin" })"></div>
<input id="BTN" type="button" value="Button" />

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/areas/admin/scripts/myscript.js")"></script>
}
```

Here you could notice that I have replaced the type of the button from `submit` to `button` because this button is not contained within a form to submit. I have also gotten rid of the `<p>` element you were having with `id="myForm"` which was not only useless but you were ending up with duplicate ids in your DOM which is invalid markup. I have also used the `data-url` HTML5 attribute on the container div to indicate the url of the server side script that will load the form. And the last thing I did in this file was to override the `scripts` section we defined earlier in the Layout with a custom script.

So the next part is the custom script: `~/areas/admin/scripts/myscript.js`:

```
$('#BTN').click(function () {
    var $formContainer = $('#formContainer');
    var url = $formContainer.attr('data-url');
    $formContainer.load(url, function () {
        var $form = $('#myForm');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
        $form.submit(function () {
            var $form = $(this);
            if ($form.valid()) {
                $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                    $form.html(data);
                    $form.removeData('validator');
                    $form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Pretty standard code here. We subscribe to the click event of the button and load the partial using an AJAX call. As soon as this is done we instruct the unobtrusive validation framework to parse the newly added contents to our DOM. The next step is to AJAXify the form by subscribing to the `.submit` event. And because in the `success` handler we are once again replacing the contents of the container we need to instruct the unobtrusive validation framework to parse the new contents.

and finally the partial:

```
@model _1.Areas.Admin.Models.AdminModule

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index_partialPost", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(i => i.MyName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.MyName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.MyName)
    <p id="getDateTimeString"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Click here" />
}
```

Here you could notice that I have gotten rid of absolutely any traces of javascript. javascript belongs to separate files. It has nothing to do in views. You should not mix markup and scripts. When you have separate scripts not only that your dynamic markup will be much smaller but also you could take advantage of things like browser caching for the external scripts, minification, ... Another thing you will notice in this partial is that I remove the `<script>` nodes in which you were referencing jQuery and the jQuery.validate scripts. You already did that in the Layout, do not repeat it twice.

Comment: I left the required field blank and showing me error messages, this is working fine. but when, I check with debugger, it is giving `if(this).valid()` equals 1. Why ? and I can still see the server request while submitting the invalid data. I meant it should not be server until everything is submitted correctly. right?

Comment: Apparently no client side validation is attached to your partial. How is this partial loaded? If you are loading it with AJAX make sure that you instruct the unobtrusive validation framework to parse the new contents using the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` method that I use inside the success callback of the `$.post` request.

Comment: updated the JQuery code for validation. can you check once...? Issue is I am facing a crash `TypeError: $form.data(...) is undefined`

Comment: What's the purpose of `$form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);`? There's no such method `validate` so it's normal that you are getting an error. Remove this line.

Comment: crash is coming at this line `$form.data("validator", null);`

Comment: Did you even look at the code in my answer? Apparently you haven't because the code you are showing is quite different. I have just updated it by adding `$('#myForm').removeData('validator');` in the success callback. I think that's what was missing. Try it now. But try it exactly as shown in my answer.

Comment: if  leave the required field blank even then it passes the condition `$(this).valid()`

Comment: Possible reasons for that is because you forgot to include the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script to your page or this partial is loaded with AJAX and you didn't call the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` method or your view model is not decorated with validation attributes. How is this partial view loaded initially?

Comment: @SMC Please follow what Darin is saying. I doubt he could be more clear. He has even given you a working example. If you continually look up your own resources and change your code it will become increasingly hard to help you.

Comment: @darindimitrov - you know very well you can answer anything. well it's fixed. last query. once the form is validated it is redirecting me to 404. Then i made a modification in your code. like this only `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index_partialPost", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))` now redirecting me to partial view page `http://localhost:1561/Admin/Admin/Index_partialPost` but this should not happen it should be remained in the View.

Comment: Try debugging the code. Does it enter the `if ($(this).valid())` condition? Is the AJAX request being sent? Can you see it in FireBug? Also are the any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: it is saying validator is undefined.

Comment: When i opened error console it is saying error at line 101 but page source it's just showing 21 lines.

Comment: I mean on which line of the code shown in my answer is this error occurring? Is it on the `if($(this).valid())` check? In the FireBug console you should see the line contents on which the error has occurred, the line number is irrelevant.

Comment: @SMC, if you could send me your project by mail I will be happy to take a look at it and tell you why it is not working. I am starting to run out of ideas here, I don't see your real code.

Comment: @SMC, Now that you sent me your project I have gone through the code and made some modifications to it. I have updated my answer to describe the various changes that I did.