# Ajax array post using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arrays, jquery

Here is a acript that I created to generate an array:

```
var data_points = $("#bcc_datapoint_selection").find("input:checked").map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Console log output:

```
["3","4","6"]
```

Ajax post script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("BccGetMeterReadingsChart", "Widget")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { dataPoints: data_points },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#bcc_chart").html(result);
    },
    error: function () {
         alert("Seçilen kritere uygun veri bulunamadı!");
    }
}); //end ajax
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult BccGetMeterReadingsChart(string[] dataPoints)
{
    // Some code
    return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Debug output:

```
dataPoints : null
```

Request data output:

```
dataPoints%5b%5d=3&dataPoints%5b%5d=4&dataPoints%5b%5d=6
```

What am I missing? Is it a problem in an Ajax function? Or another problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `traditional` parameter to true for your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("BccGetMeterReadingsChart", "Widget")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { dataPoints: data_points },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#bcc_chart").html(result);
    },
    error: function () {
         alert("Seçilen kritere uygun veri bulunamadı!");
    }
});
```

Now the POST payload will look like this:

```
dataPoints=3&dataPoints=4&dataPoints=6
```

And the model binder will happily bind the collection of points to your action argument.

Comment: you precious help required **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743271/how-can-i-modify-my-below-mentioned-code-to-display-the-same-validation-messages)**